# Highligh days from org file date items

Tags: calendar

Say I have a org file which include some datetime records as below (maybe use other proper format if needed).

```
* practice
2023-11-01 8:00-10:00 day1
2023-11-01 12:00-14:00 day1
2023-11-02 10:00-12:00 day2
2023-11-05 8:00-10:00 day3
2023-11-07 11:00-12:00 day4
```

Then I wish when open Calendar by M-x calendar, I can see above days has been highlighted in calendar view.

Not sure if any package available for such usecase or need some elisp code to do that!